# Decrypt and Encrypt using CallBack Methods in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, encryption, cakephp-2.x

I want to use the Callbacks methods to encrypt a value before it gets stored in my database and decrypt it before showing it back in the application.

I used one of the examples provided in the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/security.html).

In my `core.php` I put the following :

```
Configure::write('Security.cipherCriptKey','su0HKssPmdbwgK6LdQLqzp0YmyaTI7zO');
```

In my Model, I used two methods:

1. **`beforeSave()`**

   ```
   public function beforeSave($options = array()) {

       $value=$this->data['Internship']['encryptedindb'];
       $encrypted = Security::encrypt($value, Configure::read('Security.cipherCriptKey'));
       $this->data['Internship']['encryptedindb'] = $encrypted;
       return true;
   }
   ```
2. **`afterFind()`**

   ```
   public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {

       foreach ($results as $key => $val) {            
           if(isset($val['Internship']['encryptedindb'])){
               $results['Internship']['encryptedindb'] = Security::decrypt($val['Internship']['encryptedindb'], Configure::read('Security.cipherCriptKey'));
           }
           return $results;
       }        
   }
   ```

The `beforeSave()` seems to be working fine, since I can see in my Database the value encrypted. However, in my view, and when I would like to see the content of the field **decrypted**, it displays it as an empty field. As if the `afterFind()` method is unable to decrypt it back (it returns always false).

Below is a screenshot of my application's view:

[image: View]

And Database with the values encrypted:

[image: DB]

Comment: I believe there is a typo in `if(isset($val[Internship]['encryptedindb']))`. You are missing the quotes of `Internship`.

Comment: yeah that was just a typo when I was pasting code in here

Comment: Please post the code exactly as you run it. The above is full of syntax errors, and makes little sense.

Comment: Sorry for the mess. I edited it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What is the data type of `Internship.encryptedindb`? Also, please confirm that `Tobeencrypted` is a custom label for field `encryptedindb`

Comment: Indeed, Tobeencrypted is actually a custom label for encryptedindb. and Internship.encryptedindb is of type TEXT in the database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `Security::encrypt($text)` uses the AES-256 algorithm to encrypt `$text`. It returns binary data, and as such, it should be stored in a binary data type, instead of a text type.

Any of the following should work:

- **BINARY**
- **VARBINARY**
- **BLOB** (TINYBLOB, BLOB, MEDIUMBLOB, and LONGBLOB).

Setting it to `VARBINARY(255)` should probably be enough.

For further reference, see:

- Function [`Security::encrypt()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/security.html#Security::encrypt).
- [Encrypt MySQL data using AES techniques](http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/encrypt-mysql-data-using-aes-techniques/)

Comment: is there any way decrypt the password?

Comment: AES-256 allows decryption of encrypted data. CakePHP provides the function `Security::decrypt()` for this purpose.